# alias in cshell with grave accents, apostrophes and more

Tags: shell, alias, csh

I came across a weird behavior in the c-shell:
when writing the following line, i get exactly the behavior I expect:

```
    ls -l | grep $USER | somescript `awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`
```

meaning - it will search all items owned by me and activate 'somescript' with their first field as argument.

however, when I try aliasing the same line, it jams my shell (or hands out error massages if i separate the braces from the apostrophe:

```
    alias doit 'ls -l | grep $USER | somescript `awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`'
```

will result in either

> {: Command not found
>
> print: Command not found

or simply not being able to start a new terminal as it gets jammed.

any idea how can alias this thing (and similar things - this is just an example) without killing my shell?

Comment: http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the hell that is `csh`. I'm not sure this answer will prevent you from killing yourself, but...

```
% alias doit 'ls -l | grep $USER | somescript `awk -F'"'"' '"'"' '"'"'{print $1}'"'"'`'
```

Result:

```
% alias | grep doit
doit    ls -l | grep $USER | somescript `awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`
```

It's basically a concatenation of strings, each in alternating quotes:

```
'ls -l | grep $USER | somescript `awk -F'
"'"
' '
"'"
' '
"'"
'{print $1}'
"'"
'`'
```

(Yes, this could be simplified, but I wanted to show a consistent, general procedure for aliasing commands containing single-quotes.)

Comment: That did the trick. Amazing how awful this csh can be... Thanks!