# What does this alias do in Red Hat Linux?

Tags: rhel, csh

```
cd = 'cd !* ;set prompt="! $host `dirs` % "'
```

This alias is on a Red Hat Enterprise linux server I use commonly, and I can't figure out what it does for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't look like Bash to me.

Comment: Doesn't the cd command operate within the bash shell?

Comment: Yes, Bash *does* have a builtin `cd`, but the assignment here has spaces, and uses `set` differently from any way I know of using it in Bash.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://superuser.com OR http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: This is no default alias from bash, tcsh and ksh from RHEL7.

Comment: @user2602925: Which shell and version do you use?

Comment: csh in Red Hat Enterprise 7.something

Answer (score 0):

I think it is meant to change the directory and display the previous directories in the prompt. `!*` is a bash history expansion meaning the previous command without the first word. E.g. if the previous command was `cd project`, then `!*` is `project`. See the History Expansion section in `man bash`, more specifically [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html#Word-Designators).

[`dirs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Directory-Stack-Builtins.html) simply displays the stack of directories, and is a bash builtin, see the link for details.

However, in standard bash, you'd use `export  PS1=...` instead of `set prompt=`, so perhaps the author of the alias meant it to be used in `csh` rather than `bash`, e.g. see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/399047/customizing-csh-prompt). The history expansion `!*` has the same semantics, e.g. see [here](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/History_substitution.html) for `tcsh`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to run any differently than the normal cd command, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: I don't have access to a RHEL host, but in standard bash, you'd use `export  PS1=...` instead of `set prompt=`. Maybe that's why you don't see a change.

Comment: I think the author of the alias meant it to be used in `csh` rather than `bash`, e.g. see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/399047/customizing-csh-prompt).

Answer (score 0):

In csh aliasing, `!*` is the input the command received, e.g.
`alias + emacs \!* &` and running `+ somefile` will open somefile using emacs and move it to the background.
Now to your line - it changes directory to whatever you give it (!*) and sets the prompt (the line written in your terminal before your writing zone) to the host name, path (as `pwd`) and %

Just a quick note - pay attention to the `\` in my alias line - you must escape special characters in your alias and pay attention to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300776/alias-in-cshell-with-grave-accents-apostrophes-and-more)